# How to redirect users to log in page when they try to access the order page, but not when they try to check out

Tags: commerce, users

I'm using [Checkout Login module](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_checkout_login) that adds an inline login form to the account information checkout pane. No anonymous users have to activate their accounts to complete checkout or payment, which is all I want. However, after the PayPal redirects users back to my site, and users try to access the order (order history) page, the following message appears:

> You are not authorized to access this page.

Is there a way I can re-direct users to login page when they try to access the order page, rather than the above message appearing?

In short, I want my users to be redirected to login page when they try to access order (order history) page, but not when they try to checkout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's one of the main features of the [LoginToboggan](https://www.drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) module.

[image]

When the *Present login form on access denied (403)* is enabled in its setting form, any access denied page will display a login page. Upon login, users are redirected back to the previously requested path.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can handle it with `Rules`, create a rule in `admin/config/workflow/rules/reaction/add` and in `react on event` select `commerce order is view` (or completing the checkout process) then add condition that `if user not logged in`  on action `Redirect` user to login page.

Comment: Thanks zhilevan for the advice. I forgot to mention that I also want my users to be redirected to the same 'order history' page once they log in. The module: LoginToboggan did the job for me ..